# Meaning of "einzelnen kleinen"?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I am working through [this topic](http://www.dw.com/de/autismus-gef%C3%BChle-lesen-lernen/l-37760959) and came across this phrase:

> Autisten sollen verstehen, welche einzelnen kleinen Bewegungen welchem Gefühlszustand entsprechen.

Google translates it as:

> Autists should understand which individual movements correspond to which state of mind.

Is this correct? I'm wondering where the *kleinen* (= small) went?

I would have translated it as:

> The autists should understand which specific tiny movements correspond to which emotional condition.

Would this be correct too? Or is *einzelnen kleinen* some sort of idiom I'm unfamiliar with?

Comment: I guess it was a typoe and  your suggestion should contain "autists" instead of "autistic". "Autistic" is the adjective. I fixed that anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your translation is correct. "einzelnen kleinen" is no common term but two conjugated adjectives: "einzelnen" is individual or specific in this context and "klein" means little or tiny.